# AKS - Using Azure App Gateway in front of Traefik Ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, traefik

I have the following scenario:

- AKS Kubernetes Cluster
- Traefik Ingress Controller
- Some apps deployed inside K8s, using IngressRoutes to have different routes

Now I want to have an Azure App Gateway in front of Traefik, which does TLS termination and routes every traffic to Traefik Ingress Controller. Unfortunately, I could not find the right configuration or any docs to make it happen. Can you guys hint me in the right direction?

Comment: I think your App Gateway needs to point to a load balancer in your Ingress Controller. The load balancer should have its own public ip that you can forward traffic to.

Answer (score 0):

Since both does the same L7 load balancing/routing/Tls Termination. I would suggest deleting the traefik and use Application Gateway Ingress Controller Instead.

https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/

Pros: You get one less component in the system
Cons: Locked in to Azure, difficult to port out

If you still want to keep both, it is pretty straightforward configuration as you get a static ip(or DNS) that can be put in the backend pool of Application gateway.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the way that you mentioned, adding Traefik DNS to Application Gateway HTTP setting. The Backend Health shows it healthy. In order to test the WAF for it, I sent a request to Traefik ingress DNS and ran this query to see if any logs come under WAF: AzureDiagnostics | where Category == "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog" and hostname_s has "my DNS" however it doesn't show any record. Do you know how I can check if WAF works for it?